# LINQ with group new and by new

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq and I don't understand the part of the following program
'group new { b, c} by new { a }', can someone tell me?

Where can I refer to this,especially 'by new { a }'.

```
   from a in aTemp
   join b in bTemp on a.No equals b.No into bTB
   from b in bTB.DefaultIfEmpty()
   join c in cTemp on new { pa1 = b?.No ?? "", pa2 = b?.FNo ?? "" } 
               equals new { pa1 = c.No, pa2 = c.FNo } into cTB
   from c in cTB().DefaultIfEmpty()
   group new { b, c} by new { a } into z
   select new Log.Set
```

Comment: The line `group new { b, c} by new { a } into z` would be better written as `group new { b, c} by a into z`

Comment: Are you unsure how grouping works or anonymous types?

Comment: Thanks, Here's a program I maintain for other people, but I'm not too familiar with the linq part, and I have been trying to figure out

Comment: The variable names are awful. I think you'd understand it better with better names.

Comment: Also, it's not real code. You should post the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be the equivalent SQL query for you and with this, you can easily visualize it.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM aTemp a
LEFT JOIN bTemp b ON a.No = b.No
LEFT JOIN cTemp c ON (b.No = c.No OR b.No IS NULL) AND (b.FNo = c.FNo OR b.FNo IS NULL)
GROUP BY a.*
```

`group new { b, c }` creates a group by combining the values of `b` and `c` into a new object. It means that we want to group elements together based on their `b` and `c` values.

`by new { a }` specifies that we want to group the elements based on the value of `a`. It creates another object with a single property `a` that represents the variable a from the outer query.

`into z` assigns a name (`z` in this case) to the resulting groups of data. It's like giving a label to the groups so that we can refer to them later.

So, overall, this part of the LINQ query groups the elements based on the values of `a`. Within each group, we have the corresponding values of `b` and `c` associated with that specific `a` value. The label `z` is used to refer to these groups in further processing.

In simpler terms, think of it as putting similar elements together based on the values of `a`. Each group contains the related values of `b` and `c` for that particular `a` value.

Comment: Thank for your answer ,but I try to convert the program to mssql the last line '*' will show it not correct.

Comment: @Bernie sorry my bad, you could do like this 
GROUP BY a.Column1, a.Column2, ...